# What is father's day in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, calendarium

Today happens to be father's day in Finland, and I would like to know how to express that in Latin.
My understanding is that ancient Romans did not have a father's day, so the question is about translation.
How should I say "father's day in Latin" and why?

*Dies patris* is one way to put it, but perhaps *dies patrius* would be better.
What adjective should I use if using one is better than going with the genitive?
Should *dies* be masculine or feminine in this use?
Or should I express it in some other way?

Comment: If you go with the genitive, I would say dies patrium, because it is a day for all fathers.

Comment: @BenjaminMcAvoy-Bickford Weirdly enough, in Finnish we have father's day (singular) and mothers' day (plural). I can understand both singular and plural, but perhaps plural is indeed a little more natural.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Holidays were festivals and marked by an adjectival form in the neuter plural. Based on similar festivals, it would probably be **patralia**. Compare similar examples:

- Saturnalia, the festival of Saturnus
- Parentalia, the festival commemorating your ancestors
- Parilia, founding date of Rome

Comment: Ingenious! Presumably for a rite dedicated to a god Patuta?

Answer (score 5):

I like to keep these things snappy and simple. *Dies patribus* — a day for fathers — expresses the spirit of the occasion and will answer in most situations.